# My hosted Azure build is failing with "rzc discover exited with code -2147450730"

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I updated to the latest dotnet 3.1 SDK, and now my build is failing with the following error:

> rzc discover exited with code -2147450730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the old dotnet 2.2 SDK.

Here's what your yaml script should include:

```
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '2.2.300'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.1.100'
```